# Is passing a dependency from one private method to another a bad practice of dependency injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have an adapter - Radius class - which is as far as I understand is a dependency and I'm not really sure as to whether leave it as it is but then it is confusing to pass it as an argument to the next private method OR may be there is a way to deal with it which is more sophisticated? I know that question is not very clear but main point is that **having a dependency class passed from one private method to another is a bad practice or not?**

```
public void drawClock(Canvas canvas, float clockHandRotationAngles[], Radius radius, ArrayList<ClockElement> clockElements, ArrayList<Paint> clockHandPaintList, ClockHandDrawingType clockHandDrawingType) {
    canvas.drawArc(rect, STARTING_ANGLE_FOR_CIRCLE_DRAWING, DEGREES_IN_CIRCLE, true, circlePaint);
    for (int i = 0; i < clockHandRotationAngles.length; i++) {
        drawClockHand(canvas, clockHandRotationAngles[i], radius.getRadiusOfSpinning(clockElements.get(i)), clockHandPaintList.get(i), clockHandDrawingType);
    }
}

private void drawClockHand(Canvas canvas, float clockHandRotationAngle, int clockHandLength, Paint clockHandPaint, ClockHandDrawingType clockHandDrawingType) {
    switch (clockHandDrawingType) {
        case ARC:
            drawArc(canvas, clockHandRotationAngle, clockHandLength, clockHandPaint);
            break;
        case LINE:
            drawLine(canvas, clockHandRotationAngle, clockHandLength, clockHandPaint);
            break;
    }
}

private void drawArc(Canvas canvas, float angle, int radius, Paint paint) {
    setAppropriateRectForInnerCircle(canvasCenter, radius);
    canvas.drawArc(innerRect, STARTING_ANGLE_FOR_CIRCLE_DRAWING, angle, true, paint);
}

private void drawLine(Canvas canvas, float angle, int length, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawLine(canvasCenter.getX(), canvasCenter.getY(),
            calculateCoordinateOfRotation(Coordinate.X, angle, length),
            calculateCoordinateOfRotation(Coordinate.Y, angle, length), paint);
}
```

Comment: If you're repeating yourself constantly, then you should ask whether there's a clean way to reduce the repetition (DRY); in this case, that's *exactly* what fields are for.

Comment: @chrylis Ohhh, thank you very much! I haven't read about DRY yet and I tried to avoid using fields but if it is better to do it with them then fine:) Also, can you please put an this as an answer so that I would pick it as the best one?

Comment: By the way, you didn't show what class these are in. It's possible that depending on what the class is, all of these should be pulled out into their own (see also the Single Responsibility Principle).

Answer (score 0):

Usually dependency is injected while instantiating the class through constructor.There is no need to pass it for each private method or any method within class.Keep the reference to dependent class instance as a field.

```
Class A{
 B b;
 A(B bb){
 this.b=bb
 }

 private void someMethod(){
 //use b if required
 }
}
```

where B is some class A is dependent upon.